# Add new @keyframes animation to css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can not add a new animation to css. Do you know what the solution can be?

```
var val = "@keyframes animation{0%{color:red;}100%{color:blue;}}";
var styleAnim = document.styleSheets[0];
styleAnim.insertRule(val, document.styleSheets[0].cssRules.length);
//Error:
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertRule' on 'CSSStyleSheet': Failed to parse the rule '@keyframes animation{0%{color:red;}100%{color:blue;}}'
```

Comment: Please post the complete @keyframes rule.

Comment: @Joulss try to see now

Comment: Weird, I tried and it works... See https://jsfiddle.net/ta10wx9a/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant just update the rule (of animation keyframes) apparently. You need to remove it first and then add a new one. See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lmj7y5vm/2/

Assuming keyframes is the last rule in your stylesheet, and that you have it written in stylesheet with index 1 (that setting works for jsFiddle):

```
document.styleSheets[1].deleteRule(document.styleSheets[1].cssRules.length-1);
document.styleSheets[1].insertRule(newRule, document.styleSheets[1].cssRules.length-1);
```

Try clicking the paragraph.